# use system classpath for ant javac task

Tags: java, ant, classpath

I want the javac task to use jars from the system classpath, by which I mean the classpath that is set in the shell's environment before ant is started. That classpath is

```
CLASSPATH=D:\local\lib\java\*;.;C:\lib\java\*;C:\lib\java\db\*
```

on my system. I have popular jars there that are used by many projects. The basic snippet I use in the build file is

```
<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="${obj}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${obj}"
        includes="**/*.java"
        excludes="**/package-info.java **/deprecated/*.java"
        includeAntRuntime="no" debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines"
    >
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

That way ant only passes the output directory as classpath.

```
[javac] '-classpath'
[javac] 'D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc\obj'
```

(jsonc is the project I'm working on, and `D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc` is the working directory.)
I browsed the documentation for a while and came up with two attempts. First one was adding the attribute `classpath="${java.class.path}"` to the javac tag. That would pass a tremendously long classpath to the compiler, listing every single jar from ant's own lib directory and finally tools.jar from the JDK. Not the classpath that I wanted.

The second shot was setting

```
    <property name="build.sysclasspath" value="first" />
```

before javac was invoked, and that got me in the right direction. Now these lines were among the output:

```
dropping D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc\D:\local\lib\java\* from path as it doesn't exist
dropping D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc\C:\lib\java\* from path as it doesn't exist
dropping D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc\C:\lib\java\db\* from path as it doesn't exist
dropping D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar from path as it doesn't exist
dropping D:\dev\tbull-projects\jsonc\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\classes from path as it doesn't exist
```

Well, you can imagine that these paths really don't exist. I just don't get why ant constructed them this way. It would know how to do path arithmetic on Windows, would it?

Maybe my approach is flawed more fundamentally, so I'll let you know what I'm actually after. So I'm developing this project (a library), which uses another library. The project is gonna be open source, so I want other developers to be able to build it after they have downloaded the dependency library and placed it somewhere in *their* classpath.

From what I saw in other questions about ant+classpath, it appears that it's a custom fashion to distribute the dependency libs with the source code (so the classpath can be just like ./libs). But I surely don't want to have jars in my git repo. So how could that be done?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every person who's broken a build by using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable, I could retire. **Don't do it.** Whatever you think you're gaining, you're not, and you're causing pain for yourself or someone else down the road.

Comment: And, since your goal is dependency management, take a look at Maven: http://maven.apache.org/ -- it has its flaws, but is remarkably easy to set up ... just follow the tutorial.

Comment: Maven might be lots of things, but easy isn't one of them.  And it forces you to do things its way.  Your classpath advice is spot on, Anon, but I disagree with the Maven comment.

Comment: @Anon: maven is really not my way, it's far to complicated and it doesn't respect my preferences. As for the classpath, could you elaborate why it is a problem to use it? I thought, environment variables are there to refer to them.

Comment: @duffymo - I guess I've just seen far too many multi-thousand-line Ant scripts ... including multiple large scripts for the same project that are all configured differently. I *like* Ant; it's a great tool for complex builds. But 99.9% of the Java projects that I've seen are anything but complex, and could be built using the POM from the "5 Minute Tutorial": http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Comment: @duffymo - And while you may not like being forced to do things in Maven's way, do you really prefer a world where "I think every developer should have the possibility to define an own classpath (or any other env var"?

Comment: Not me - I've got one that works fine, and it's generic enough where I reuse it all over the place.  It's really an XML make file for me.  I hate the way Maven forces me to conform to their directory layout - no exceptions.  Please tell me that there's a way to customize it and I'll think kindly of you and Maven.

Comment: I prefer a world where I'm not forced.  I have a good reason for wanting to do it the way that I do, and it has nothing to with classpath.  I know how to manage it just fine, thank you.

Comment: @duffymo: So how do _you_ handle the dependency problem?

Comment: @duffymo - if you post a question of how to configure Maven's source paths, I'll write an answer :-) Or look here: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Directories

Comment: @duffymo - and believe me, I have some very strong complaints about Maven. But directory structures aren't one of them.

Comment: Not interested.  Maven ain't it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Soo... seems I have to answer the question myself. Passing the original classpath to the javac task can be achieved with this:

```
<!-- load environment into the env property -->
<property environment="env" />

<javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${obj}"
    includes="**/*.java"
    excludes="**/package-info.java **/deprecated/*.java"
    includeAntRuntime="no" includeJavaRuntime="no"
    debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines"
>
    <!-- add -classpath option manually -->
    <compilerarg value="-classpath" />
    <compilerarg value="${env.CLASSPATH}" />
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
</javac>
```

That does the trick at least so far that the javac task now gets passed the correct classpath. Yet it will still not work, javac now spits these complaints:

```
[javac] warning: [path] bad path element "D:\local\lib\java\*": no such file or directory
[javac] warning: [path] bad path element "C:\lib\java\*": no such file or directory
[javac] warning: [path] bad path element "C:\lib\java\db\*": no such file or directory
```

This is a straight lie, these paths do very much exist. I use them all the time, and if I manually craft an equivalent javac invocation at the shell, it works like a charm. I suspect ant's javac doesn't resolve the jar files in those directories. I have to examine that.

**UPDATE**

It is indeed as I suspected, the wildcard is not resolved to the individual present jar files by the javac task. I managed to do the resolving manually, and now it works as it should. And that resolving was in fact a struggle on its own. So I'll leave the solution here for those poor souls fighting the same stupidity, hopefully before they ask people that have nothing else to do than bullshitting around (yes Anon, talking about you).

Turns out, ant lacks the most basic functionality that you would expect from a build tool. Also turns out that I'm not the first one to notice that. While solutions are rare, there *is* a very good post about [Using JavaScript to make Apache Ant less painful](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/emcmanus/archive/2010/09/20/using-javascript-make-apache-ant-less-painful), which really saved my day. Yes, ant can indeed be scripted, which seems not to be widely known, although it is [not kept secret](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html). You can safely assume, that Javascript is already available without installing additional libraries if you run ant on Java 6.

Soo... down to business. Here is the thing:

```
<target name="expand_classpath">
    <script language="javascript"><![CDATA[
        // the original classpath
        var ocp = java.lang.System.getenv("CLASSPATH");
        //  ... split in parts
        var ocp_parts = ocp.split(project.getProperty("path.separator"));

        // where our individual jar filenames go,
        //  together with pure directories from ocp_parts
        var expanded_parts = [ ];

        for each (var part in ocp_parts) {
            if (part.endsWith('*')) {
                var dir = part.substring(0, part.length() - 1);
                var f = new java.io.File(dir);

                // don't know how to construct a java.io.FilenameFilter,
                //  therefore filter the filenames manually
                for each (var file in f.listFiles())
                    if (file.getPath().endsWith('.jar'))
                        expanded_parts.push(file.getPath());
            } else
                expanded_parts.push(part);
        }

        var expanded = expanded_parts.join(project.getProperty("path.separator"));
        project.setProperty("classpath.expanded", expanded);
    ]]></script>

    <!-- <echo message="classpath.expanded = ${classpath.expanded}" /> -->
</target>

<target name="build" depends="expand_classpath">
    <mkdir dir="${obj}" />

    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${obj}"
        classpath="${classpath.expanded}"
        includes="**/*.java"
        excludes="**/package-info.java **/deprecated/*.java"
        includeAntRuntime="no" includeJavaRuntime="no"
        debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines"
    >
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-fallthrough"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: This might just be the most idiotic posting that I have ever seen on SO. First you whine about the tool. Then you whine about the people who try to teach you how to use the tool properly. Then you post this dreck. If you want a shell script, why don't you just write a shell script? -1, and if I could post an anti-bounty I would.

Comment: +1 for actually reasoning why you downvoted me. :-) But: I asked the people several times to educate me, yet they refused to do so, so I have to assume they don't actually know what they talk about. (Just saying "don't do that" without any explanation is not the way teachers talk, it's the way idiots talk.) And regarding shell scripts, I value their flexibility very much, but they are unfortunately not cross-platform. The same goes for make. I chose ant specifically because it was the nearest I could find to traditional make files.

Answer (score 3):

Set includeJavaRuntime=true in javac task.

```
<target name="build">
    <mkdir dir="${obj}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${obj}"
        includes="**/*.java"
        excludes="**/package-info.java **/deprecated/*.java"
        includeAntRuntime="no" includeJavaRuntime="true"
        debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines">
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
    </javac>
</target>
```

Comment: +1 for at least trying to answer my question, in contrast to the ignorant people in this thread. Unfortunately, the answer is not correct. `includeJavaRuntime` extends the classpath argument by the path to the JRE jars, like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\jre\lib\rt.jar` in my case. The originally defined cp doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Why *wouldn't* you set CLASSPATH in Ant?  It's perfectly suited to do just that.  You're making a mistake if you do anything else.  Not only will it work, bu your build.xml will document the requirements as well.

Comment: I think every developer should have the possibility to define an own classpath (or any other env var, after all that's what they are for). (I'm not talking about company network here, but independent developers.)

Comment: Addendum: If i hardcode the cp in the build file, every developer has to edit it for his own environment, which is not only unpleasant, also it leads to conflicts when merging changes. Didn't we all learn that hardcoding is bad?

Comment: No, dependencies should be in your project in /lib and /test-lib files.  I agree that developer-dependent classpaths are bad, but that's not what I'm recommending.

Answer (score 1):

When javac compiles the code , it tries to find the files in rt.jar in a symbol file called ct.sym (which is also present in lib directory). some files are missing in this symbol file.
i have to add a compile option to ignore symbol file and look directly in rt.jar.

so i have used this option -XDignore.symbol.file for ant i put this value in javac tag. it works perfectly if you use eclipse or any other ide .

```
<compilerarg value="-XDignore.symbol.file"/>
```

So , whenever you get ClassNotFoundException in using classes from rt.jar , and if the class is still present there , just try to add this argument in java compiler

To reference rt.jar from ant you may use:

```
<fileset dir="${java.home}/lib" includes="rt.jar"/>
```

Original details were found here: http://www.javaroots.com/2013/01/javac-error-using-classes-from-rtjar.html

Answer (score 0):

If someone is new to java/ANT world, people who suggest maven are idiots
whatever happened to KISS principle?

OP, instead of using javascript abomination try this

```
<project default="build">
<property name="src" value="src" />
<property name="obj" value="obj" />

<property name="parent.dir" value="/jakarta-tomcat/common/lib" />
<path id="project.class.path">
    <pathelement location="lib/" />
    <fileset dir="${parent.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</path>

<target name="build">
    <delete dir="${obj}" />
    <mkdir dir="${obj}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${obj}" includes="**/*.java" excludes="**/package-info.java **/deprecated/*.java" debug="true" debuglevel="source,lines" classpathref="project.class.path" />
</target>
```

Comment: You supply a handcrafted classpath by including all jars beneath a location hardcoded in the ant file. And this is _how_ exactly related to my question? Not downvoting you though for mentioning the KISS principle, which I value very much and is indeed the driving force behind the question (although my eventual answer doesn't seem to fit in well).

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear the folks behind `java`, and (or at least), `ant`, really really really don't want to see `$CLASSPATH` end up as storage for user installed libraries of the sort that 95% of other mainstream languages (C/C++, perl, python, ruby, etc. etc.) use.  So this is a tough paradigm to swallow if you are used to general programming in most other mainstream languages.

The disinclination goes so far that it is obvious `ant` *intentionally* strips `$CLASSPATH` out of the environment, but an easy way around this is to just use a different variable.

```
 <property name="classpath" location="${env.JAVALIBPATH}"/>
```

This will then work, no fuss, with both `<javac>` and `<java>` commands (`classpath="${classpath}`) which is good, because if you try this instead:

```
 <property name="classpath" location="${env.CLASSPATH}"/>
```

There is no `includeAntRuntime="false"` option to `<java>` which would allow this to work.  You simply cannot get `$CLASSPATH` in and someone has gone to lengths to make sure of it (without, apparently, and yikes, adding in a ponderous javascript hack).

Of course that means you need to use a separate env variable and for your distributed/production version stick to the Java "Sorry no user libs!" paradigm.  That's not a big problem if you use a variable name that, if it becomes involved, will almost certainly be undefined on the target system.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, there are the [Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html). These will allow you to use Maven's dependency mechanism in a way that, IMO, is cleaner than Ivy. But it's still not a great solution.

Comment: And, as a sidenote to this: I think you said you were creating an open-source library. Most of the professional programmers that I know won't use a library that isn't available from Maven Central. The Maven Ant tasks will at least let you create a deployable artifact.

Answer (score -2):

I will assume that your "popular" JARs are well-known open-source projects. This means that they're available in the Maven central repository.

While I believe that using Maven is the *best* answer to this question, you can also hack something using Ant's `<get>` task. For example, to download the JUnit JAR (may have typos):

```
<property name="dependency.dir" value="${basedir}/dependencies"/>

<property name="junit.jar" value="junit-4.8.2.jar"/>
<property name="junit.url" value="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=junit/junit/4.8.2/${junit.jar}"/>

<target name="download.dependencies">
    <mkdir dir="${dependency.dir}/>
    <get url="${junit.url}" dest="${dependency.dir}/${junit.jar}"/>
</target>
```

Of course, if you do this then you'll have to carefully configure your build scripts so that you don't do the download with every run. And you'll increase load on the Maven Central repository.

Comment: Could you point me to the exact location in my text where I asked for how to download a dependency? Probably not. If I could I would downvote you like -10 for this silly post. Please, just go away!